# How postgres btree index works for string columns

Tags: postgresql

I couldn't find enough information on Postgres documentations but curious to know how does btree index look like for a postgres varchar column.

Any links / explanations might be helpful.

PS: Sorry for the vague question

Answer (score 2):

One good place to start is in the code ( and its contained documentation ).

Download here:
http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v9.4.1/

unpack the archive and look for the README under src/backend/access/nbtree/. That should give you quite a good introduction into what they're up to.

If you're ambitious and can read C code, you can have a look at the implementation in there too. Hope this helps.

Comment: [PostgreSQL source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/) is also browsable online.